# strip http:// from the_author_url()

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get rid of the http:// for this:

```
<a href="<?php the_author_url(); ?>"><?php the_author_url() ); ?></a>
```

I've tried this:

```
<a href="<?php the_author_url(); ?>">
  <?php $url =  the_author_url();
  $url = substr($url,0,6);
  echo $url; ?>
</a>
```

but it had no effect...

Comment: What about trying `str_replace()`? `str_replace("http://", "", the_author_url());`

Comment: Note that the function is deprecated. You should use [`the_author_meta('user_url')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_url) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_author_meta()` won't work, because that function `echo`es the result. Instead, you need to use `get_the_author_meta('user_url')`, which `return`s the URL.

```
<a href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url'); ?>">
    <?php echo str_replace('http://', '', get_the_author_meta('user_url')); ?>
</a>
```

Note that this doesn't account for `https` URLs (you can use a regex replace function for that, if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Well you almost got it right. Try using this:

```
<?php
function the_author_url(){
  return 'http://www.google.com';
}
$url = substr(the_author_url(),7);

?>
<a href="<?=the_author_url()?>"><?=$url?></a>
```

Or something like this:

```
<?php
function the_author_url(){
  return 'http://www.google.com';
}
$url = str_replace('http://','',the_author_url());

?>
<a href="<?=the_author_url()?>"><?=$url?></a>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/207127

Comment: <?php 
 $url = str_replace("http://", "", the_author_meta('user_url'));
 echo $url;
?>

Comment: Thanks for the help, it, seems perfectly fine to me - but the above isn't working for me - any idea what I'm doing wrong? :-/